# How to correctly treat fupes (=fake dupes)?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527724/build-a-dictionary-for-find-key-by-value) (asking for a bidirectional mapping in Python) which is closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456373/two-way-reverse-map) (asking for the same but *restricted* to the set mapping to itself). The latter is only is special case, and there actually exists a [third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/efficient-bidirectional-hash-table-in-python) which would be a better dupe-candidate. I flagged the first question and left a comment, is there anything else I should do, e.g. leaving a post at meta.SO for *each* such case?

Comment: @Martijn Thanks, I should wake up for real before posting stuff...

Comment: Leaving a post on Meta won't achieve much in any case. Or we would have to reopen it only to close it again as the other dupe. Just leave a comment I'd say.

Comment: @Bart Not even flagging? While the closing happened this year, the question in question is .6̅6 years old, so how likely is commented to be spotted by anyone but the OP?

Comment: I'll leave it up to a moderator to answer that. I don't know how likely they are to insta-reopen-close a question to put in a more canonical dupe.

Comment: @Bart flags can also be seen by [10k users](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), and a single reopen vote would at least add the question to the review queue

Comment: Point is though that ultimately you want to see the question closed as a dupe, right? If that is the case, having the community reopen it seems pointless and might not even happen.

Comment: @Bart Point is, if the supposed duplicate treats a more general case, then either the _direction_ of closure is wrong (independently of question age), or as in this case there is another question of which it _really_ is a duplicate. Or as a third possibility, a question might not be a dupe at all and only be wrongly closed as such. I know _I_ did dupe-vote questions that, after reading them a second time, turned out to not be a duplicate

Comment: If they are truly not dupes, vote to reopen them. Or flag to have them reopened. But if you think the dupe is correct, but there is a more canonical dupe for it, voting to reopen might not be the best approach. Like I said, a moderator can do an insta-reopen-close thing. But I don't know how willing they are in general to do so. If they are not, flagging for it is pointless. So let's see.

Comment: @Bart Yes and No... I agree with flagging; but if the dupe is _incorrect_, the questions must not be closed as a duplicate of _that_ question, no matter whether there exists another question of which it _is_ a duplicate (as which it should then be re-closed) or _not_

Answer (score 1):

If you only disagree with the question that have been selected as duplicate, then leave a comment pointing to the question you think the closed question is really duplicating.
As moderator, I would not re-open a question to close it with a different reason, or as duplicated of a different question.

If you think the question should stay open, then vote to re-open it or, if you cannot do that, flag for moderation attention and explain it was wrongly closed. I would rather use the latter option if the question is very old and there aren't chances the question is noted from somebody else. If there is an active chat linked to the Stack Exchange site, I would ask in that chat room if the question should not be open; if somebody agree with you, they will vote to re-open it.

Comment: But that leaves the wrong "This question already has an answer here:" hint at the very top of the question. Consider it a two-step process: Step 1) Reopen the question, since it is _not_ a duplicate of the other one. Step 2) Close it as a duplicate of another one. If step two were not present, would you leave the question wrongly closed? No. What you are suggesting is **doing the right thing for the wrong reasons** (However +1 for the second paragraph, so -0 in total)

Comment: If "Step 2" is not possible, it means the question has been wrongly closed as duplicate and should be re-opened, if the question should not be closed for any other reason. What would you do if you see a question that has been closed as not constructive when you think it should be closed as not a real question? Do you vote to re-open it, and then vote to close it when it gets re-opened?

Comment: That's a different beast, not constructive and not a real question both mean that a question shouldn't have been here first place; a duplicate is on-topic but happens to have been asked before.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate isn't really to say "this has been asked before", but instead to say "this has been *answered* before, and here's where you can find it"; if that's not actually the case then the closure is, as far as I'm concerned, invalid.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler In both the cases, you object the closing reason; in the case of duplicated questions, you say that "duplicate of X" is wrong, and "duplicate of Y" is correct.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist If there isn't any duplicated question, then closing as duplicate is surely wrong. What I mean is that, practically, nobody is going to re-open a closed question just to close it for the right reason.

Comment: @kiamlaluno There's a significant difference between closing as not constructive when it should have been not a real question (or vice versa) and closing as a duplicate of X when it's not, and is in fact a duplicate of Y. Questions that are closed as duplicates serve a specific purpose, they're signposts to point people to the previously posted answer, and they need to be closed correctly in order to achieve that. Are people likely to re-open just to close for the right reason? Probably not. Should they? Yes for duplicates.